# How to remove labels on the chart when using MPAndroidChart Library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to use `MPAndroidChartLibrary` for charting and could draw the chart. I have two questions in the graph:

- I don't want the values to be added on the graph
- I don't want the horizontal and vertical lines while scrubbing, instead I want a bubble or a small circle on the chart line (not sure if this is possible).

Please help me, what api can I use in `MPAndroidChart` to achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few different questions in here

**How to get rid of values?**

To hide the values drawn at each point, you can call `setDrawValues(false)` on the data set.

**How to get rid of the highlighting lines?**

To disable the horizontal and vertical yellow lines when you click a point, you can use `lineSet.isHighlightEnabled = false`, however if you also want to use a chart popup you should keep it enabled, but hide the lines with `setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator` and `setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator`

**How to add a popup that shows a custom view when clicking on a point?**

To add a [popup view](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/markerview/), you need to define a class to extend `MarkerView`, an XML layout for your popup view, and then set it on the chart. I showed an example below that shows the value in a TextView - if you just want a custom icon you could just put that in the XML instead. If you aren't changing the view from one icon to the next (e.g. just showing the same icon each time) you can just use the `MarkerView` class directly, no need to extend it.

### A Complete Example

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val lineChart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.line_chart)

    val x = listOf(1f,  2f,  3f,  4f,  5f,  6f)
    val y = listOf(10f, 20f, 30f, 40f, 50f, 60f)
    val entries = x.zip(y).map { Entry(it.first, it.second) }

    val lineSet = LineDataSet(entries, "test")
    lineSet.circleRadius = 10f

    // Disable drawn values
    lineSet.setDrawValues(false)

    // Disable highlight lines
    // lineSet.isHighlightEnabled = false // this works, but also disables the marker

    // instead, leave highlighting enabled but disable the lines
    lineSet.setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(false)
    lineSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false)
    
    // Add a popup when you click a point
    lineChart.marker = ChartPopup(this)
    
    val xaxis: XAxis = lineChart.xAxis
    xaxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    xaxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    xaxis.granularity = 1f
    xaxis.isGranularityEnabled = true
    xaxis.setDrawLabels(true)
    xaxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    xaxis.setDrawGridLines(false)

    val yAxisLeft: YAxis = lineChart.axisLeft
    yAxisLeft.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART)
    yAxisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
    yAxisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    yAxisLeft.isEnabled = true
    yAxisLeft.textSize = 15f

    lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    lineChart.extraBottomOffset = 10f
    lineChart.extraLeftOffset = 10f
    lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
    lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
    
    lineChart.data = LineData(lineSet)

    lineChart.invalidate()
}
```

The chart popup class and layout

```kotlin
class ChartPopup(context: Context) : MarkerView(context, R.layout.chart_popup) {

    private var popupText: TextView? = null

    override fun refreshContent(e: Entry, highlight: Highlight?) {
        popupText?.text = "${e.y}"
        super.refreshContent(e, highlight)
    }

    private var customOffset: MPPointF? = null
    override fun getOffset(): MPPointF {
        if (customOffset == null) {
            // center the marker horizontally and vertically
            customOffset = MPPointF((-(width / 2)).toFloat(), (-height).toFloat())
        }
        return customOffset!!
    }

    init {
        popupText = findViewById(R.id.popup_text)
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_text"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's what it looks like before and after the changes, selecting the "30" point:

[image: before and after]

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks your example helped a lot